# How to determine which techniques and frameworks are supported by older browsers?

Tags: javascript, browser, frameworks, opera

I need to develop a website for a particular device which only has Opera 11 as browser which cannot be updated. For this browser I need to develop a website. Nowadays there are modern frameworks and web techniques but some of them will obviously not be supported by Opera 11. I tried building a really simple Angular application but the corresponding typescript code was converted to Javascript code which turned out to have newer functions then are supported. Even JQuery is not yet supported in this specific browser.

I am wondering if it is a good idea to even use a modern framework like Angular, React or Vue for example. How to determine which techniques and frameworks are supported by older browsers?

Thank you in advance.

Let me know if this question should not be asked on Stackoverflow.

Comment: In a nutshell: read the documentation, e.g. http://caniuse.com and the compatibility charts at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference. When compiling to Javascript, you can usually target specific Javascript versions, and perhaps you can find one low enough that it's supported. Though beyond that, frameworks will typically declare what browsers they run on. _Maybe_ you're able to find some lowest common denominator framework and compile setting; if not, tough luck.

Comment: A "modern" framework that may work on old Opera versions is early versions of AngularJS, as they're roughly from around the same timeframe. And there are probably other similar frameworks from around the same time that may work.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that Opera 11 worked in the year 2010 (16 December, 2010). It is a old browser.

The modern framework don't support old browser:

- Angular: As you can see in official documentation https://angular.io/guide/browser-support and another documentation https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/browser/ Opera 50+ is supported but not previous versions.
- React https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/browser/
- Vue: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/browser/

Old framework Backbone.js (use jQuery) and AngularJs (use a special jQuery Lite) maybe they can work in Opera 11 but you need to try it and more information about you want develop in your website.

- **I recommend you use jQuery 1.12** or always native javascript. As you can see in official jQuery link: https://jquery.com/browser-support/ and the next image https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnypL.jpg.

You can find problems while developing, this is normal too.

I hope I helped you. Good luck and coding.